# Bash crashes when executing script that defines a function with the same as an existing command

Tags: bash, function, ubuntu, recursion

I am very new to bash.  All I want to do is run this `nvvp -vm /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java` without having to remember the path at the end.  I figured the instafix would be to just do this...

```
nvvp() {
    nvvp -vm /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
}
```

Then I could just call `nvvp` and it would boot up Nvidia's Visual Profiler.  But this just crashes my terminal.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2264) and other common issues

Answer (score 4):

The redefinition of `nvvp` is global. Inside the function `nvvp` you execute that very same function, causing an infinite recursion. To call the actual binary instead of the function, use bash's `command` built-in:

```
nvvp() {
    command nvvp -vm /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It look's like a fork. Try out

```
another_name() {
nvvp -vm /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to define an alias, eg:

```
alias nvvp='nvvp -vm /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java'
```